# How to use current sources correctly

Tags: analog, current-source, spice, analog-switch, spdt

In this simulation the circuit generates a AC signal at "Electrode". Here I am using two SPDT-Switches (R<sub>on</sub> = 4 Ω).

[image: 1.Circuit]

My first question: Why isn't the signal correctly rectangular? And how can I correct that?

[image: 1. Result]

On the second circuit I am replacing the ideal current generators with current sources:

[image: 2. Circuit]

My second question: Why aren't the signals at "sw1" and "sw2" constant over time and why don't they have a similar value as in the first simulation? And how can I correct that? Or which circuit mirror implementation should I use instead?

[image: 2. Result]

[image: 2.2 Result]

[image: 2.3 Result]

I tried to plot the signals, which may be needed for the interpretation.

Comment: As I understand from the second circuit you are copying the current I1 into two directions. (into top side & bottom side of the circuit). And the opamp & bipolar implementation is used as a current source. And the current sources are cousing current errors, which are expected. There are some solutions to fix the errors.

Comment: Apparent component clutter: R4, R5, Vdd, Vss, U2_in, U1_in. If you explained what you expected to happen it might make it easier to wade through the circuit and understand it.

Comment: @Andyaka I expect, that same current flows through the emitter and through the collector of bipolar "Q2". Or same current flows through the emitter and through the collector of bipolar "Q1"

Comment: If you meant `_BBM2` to be the complementary of `BBM1`, you misaligned the pulses. Better make a "master" clock, to which add a `[Digital]/buf`, which will give you true complementary outputs (voltage levels can be set with `vhigh, vlow`, optional `ref` for input threshold). Still, I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplsh.